# Mvc Routing to specific namespace

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, razorengine

I have two controllers with the same name in the same mvc area. They are however in different namespaces and this works by adding a different route for each controller e.g.

```
routes.MapRoute("SpecialRoute", "Special/{action}/{id}/{*catchall}",
    new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "MyCom.Team1"});
```

but, when calling the following

```
Html.Action("MyController","MyAction")
```

It causes a runtime error where mvc doesn't know which of the two controllers to use. Is it possible to specify which namespace for to use in the Html.Action call ? Otherwise would it be neccesary or indeed possible to extend the mvc helper method to be able to target a specific namespace ?

Comment: If i'm right, there should be an overload in the Action method where you can add the routename.

Comment: That could work , I don't see that for the Html.Action overloads unfortunately. Only controller,action,route values.